# Background/foreground with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Sometimes, when I do "docker-compose up -d", I forget the "-d" part. So it starts to show me starting logs and if I do Ctrl + C it just terminates all the process and shows me the closing logs.

I have several questions about this :

1. If I manage to detach the process with detach keys (Ctrl P Ctrl Q by default) is it the exact same result as if I had started docker-compose with -d ?
2. Now if detach keys don't work (impossible to input Ctrl Q) is it the same result to do "Ctrl-Z" bg compared to starting docker-compose with -d ?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking.. However, I would never recommend doing a Ctrl C as that seems to leave containers running sometimes. I always suggest opening another terminal window and doing the good ole `docker-compose down` which will ensure everything is stopped/destroyed. EDIT: ok i understand what you are asking, and I'm not sure of the answer :)

Comment: Can you explain why you don't recommend Ctrl Z ? (this is what the question is about). About your other suggestion, I don't get it, because a Ctrl C will do the same thing, I'm just trying to fix a bad launch (without the "-d" option), so far, the only way is to do Ctrl C, wait until everything is down, and then docker-compose up again, but with the right "-d" option.

Comment: Sorry.. i meant Ctrl C (fixed). This guy had the same question and not sure if it ever got resolved. But the answer was to try `Ctrl-Z`, `bg` and maybe `disown`. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3936 Sorry not much help.

Comment: Oh yes thanks for this link, it may be exactly what I was looking for. So I'll try Ctrl + Z -> bg -> disown (first time I hear about this "disown" command).

Answer (score 11):

`docker-compose up` displays streaming logs. This is the main advantage over `docker-compose up -d`.

If you ran `docker-compose up -d`, it's never too late. You are still able to display those streaming logs:

```
docker-compose logs -f
```

Comment: This is not the question though. The question is about putting docker-compose in background when started in foreground.

Comment: directly? there is no way. Workaround? this answer

Comment: Your answer is about displaying logs, none of the 2 questions asked are about displaying logs.

Comment: seems you can just `docker-compose up` again to **reattach** to the detached containers (if this is what ppl search for) -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365292/attach-to-container-from-docker-compose-restarts-container