# Attach to container from docker compose restarts container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 2 services with 2 different images in my docker-compose.yml, when I run "docker-compose up -d", containers are started properly, but when i try to do "docker attach ", container restarts.

Can anyone please explain this behavior. How can attach to the container?

Comment: Can you please share your docker-compose file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you want to go to your running compose container you can start new `shell` and attach to it

```
docker-compose exec servicename sh
```

or if you really want to attach to it just do `docker-compose up`

Comment: Thanks for the command. Using this command I am able to attach to the running compose container.